# Invalid Signature on Stripe CLI

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm testing Stripe webhooks on my local environment.  I'm using:

```
./stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost/cb/stripe
./stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
```

And here is the code in my webhook:

```
 $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

    // This is your Stripe CLI webhook secret for testing your endpoint locally.
    $endpoint_secret = 'whsec...';

    $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
    $event = null;

    try {
        $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
            $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
        );
    } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        write_log('invalid payload');
        // Invalid payload
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
    } catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
        // Invalid signature
        write_log('invalid signature');
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
    }

    // Handle the event
    switch ($event->type) {
        case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            $charge = $event->data->object;
            write_log($charge);
        case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
            $charge = $event->data->object;
            write_log($charge);
        default:
            write_log('Received unknown event type ' . $event->type);
    }

    http_response_code(200);
}
```

When I run my trigger, I get the 'invalid signature' logged.

```
[400] POST http://localhost/cb/stripe [evt_3NzOP4Ivmq1M9dbl01GdMEIc]
[400] POST http://localhost/cb/stripe [evt_3NzOP4Ivmq1M9dbl0Q2mju6H]
[400] POST http://localhost/cb/stripe [evt_3NzOP4Ivmq1M9dbl0T2nZWRQ]
```

Comment: You changed `$endpoint_secret = 'whsec...';` to your actual secret, right?

Comment: yes and STRIPE_SECRET_KEY is my test secret key

Answer (score 0):

When you test these locally, you have to use the Webhook Secret that you get via the output on the command line. So, when you run `./stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost/cb/stripe`, it will give you a Webhook Secret to plug into your code.

It will look like this --> `whsec_abc123`

[image]

Comment: the key that is output is the same key that I am using in my code